# iOS unable to manipulate jQuery DOM changes on the first page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone

I've been having a weird issue with Safari on iOS.
I'm using jQuery to manipulate a couple of divs, moving them, wrapping them and giving them dynamic heights. On every browser, these changes are perfectly working during the first page load, on Safari, sometimes yes and sometimes not.

basically in Safari, it loads the page without applying any changes, then if I keep refreshing it, it never works, but if I reenter the url, on the address bar and I hit "enter", that time it works.

Now, I solved it wrapping the function that triggers those DOM manipulations in a setTimeout function and I give it a delay of 400. SO now it waits 400ms before firing the function, and this way it's working, but I don't like it that much. I was wondering if you guys know a better system.

my code:

```
    $('.wrap-services, .wrap-banner-cta, .wrap-logos, footer').wrapAll('<div class="fixer"></div>');
    $('.fixer').insertAfter('.content');

    function getHeight() {

        var imgOffset = $('.wrap-hero-home picture.splash-main img').offset().top;
        var fixerHeight = $('.fixer').height();
            imgHeight = $('.wrap-hero-home picture.splash-main img').height();

        $('.fixer').css('top', (imgOffset + imgHeight) + 50);

        $('.container').height((imgOffset + imgHeight + fixerHeight) + 50);
    }   


//this is what I use now to prevent that issue
setTimeout(getHeight, 400);
```

Thanks

Comment: Is it that you just need the page and all assets to be completely loaded? You might be able to do like this: `$(window).load(function(){/* Do something */});`

Comment: I'm already firing that function within the $(document).ready... anyway, probably this issue is caused because I don't know why in iOS, sometimes, it runs the function before the DOM is loaded

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to put that inside document ready, but outside on its own is the way I've always used it. Maybe it's worth a try.

Comment: if i move the function out of the document ready, it doesn't work at all. I tried to wrap it in $(window).load ... but it doesn't work the function at all

Comment: Maybe you should show some HTML and JS. This is, after all, Stack Overflow, a site to get help with code :)

Comment: done. so basically the function getHeight() is not fired or is fired too soon on iOS

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe I solved it, moving the function out from the document.ready and wrapping it into....
$(window).bind('load', function(){  //Do something   });

Comment: If that's the answer, I'd appreciate if you would let me create an official answer so you can accept it. Oops, I guess your code is a little different, nevermind ...

Comment: ok..................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, jQuery's bind method is deprecated, so you should probably use `on`, like they suggest:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    //Do something
});
```

See the notes in this page related to the deprecation: http://api.jquery.com/bind/

If you're using an old version of jQuery, I guess it wouldn't matter, then proceed with `bind`